# Is there anything wrong with reassigning Python variables to different types?

Tags: python-3.x, variable-assignment, standards

An example of what I'm asking is below.

I have the code:

```
html = requests.get("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
cad = soup.get_text()
cad = cad[cad.index("titlesHomepageChart"):cad.index("subTitlesHomepageChart")]
cad = cad.replace("titlesHomepageChart = ", "").replace(";", "")

cad = json.loads(cad)
print("Currency:\n" + cad['USD'] + "\n")
```

It works as intended - overwriting old values of 'cad' with subsequent ones. I am wondering if this reassigning method is commonly done.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it per se, except that it might be confusing if done other than in a very localized area as you have done here.

Comment: I don't think it is good style. It is very hard to tell what variables do it you give them all the same name.

Comment: Functionally, reusing the variable to store different type values works, as python does not require declaration of variable type, nor does python enforce strict type checking. Python is aware of the type stored in a variable. But reusing variables to store different value types can make code harder to read. This is a stye issue and you might find good feedback on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com